# Cannot uninstall python 2.7.10 from windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10

For some reason I messed up my install in python a while ago and I recently tried to repair the install but I am getting an error saying: "The specified account already exists." I then decided to rerun the install package and instead of repairing it decided to delete python so I clicked uninstall and got the error message saying: "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor." The only package I installed (if it is a package) was VPython and for some reason that does not open whenever I try opening it so I assumed I messed up the download for that also. I decided to go ahead and delete everything in my C directory that had the keyword Python including the Python27 folder but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: The registry probably still thinks you have python installed, which is why the installer will fail. I would try the CCleaner registry cleaner, then see if you can install

Comment: Agreed that this seems to be Windows-related jiggery-pokery.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem and i use advanced system optimizer and **clean registery** and **repair pytho**n then uninstall and it work for me

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this works.  Use Ccleaner to fix the registry, then use installer to "Repair" 2.7.10 the installation, then use installer to "Remove" the installation.